# how to check if user already exist facebook authentication?

Tags: mysql, flutter, facebook-authentication

i am  developing app with facebook authentication login if the user signup with his/her facebook account with email is good i can check if user already register and redirect to main screen but how to check if user signup with his/her facebook account with phone number?

```
      FacebookAuth.instance.login(
                  permissions: ["public_profile", "email"]).then((value) {

                FacebookAuth.instance.getUserData().then((userData) {

                  setState(() {

                    _isLoggedIn = true;
                    _fBauthentication.Userobject=userData;
                  });

                });
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

`await FacebookAuth.instance.accessToken;`
use this. If the value is null it means user is not logged in from the app yet, If it is not null it means there is a user logged in from your app.